# How do I connect to a WiFi network using nmcli?

Tags: wireless, network-manager

I am able to connect to a wireless network using `nm-applet` when running it in lightdm, however, it does not work in an openBox session that I start as myself (a user started X Session), but am not able to do so using nmcli.

I am running `nmcli` using `sudo`. After 90 seconds, I get a time out message. What could be wrong?

This is the configuration I must use - http://www.depts.ttu.edu/ithelpcentral/solutions/wireless/

Comment: did you check this question http://askubuntu.com/q/8322/169736 ?

Comment: From the man page of `cnetworkmanager`, I gather that it does nto support WPA2 enterprise.

Comment: Can you edit your question and add that? Since nobody would figure out why for them works and yours don't. Also I recommend editing the title so people are able to find it easier. Then post your answer below ;).

Comment: added link with my network info.

Comment: And the answer?

Comment: Answer? This is not resolved yet. I have mot  managed to connect yet. The title is fine. Nmcli does not work at all irrespective of the network.

Comment: cnetworkmanager is not part of saucy is it ?

Comment: apt did not seem to know about it

Comment: nothing reliable :-(

Answer (score 34):

1. In case the wireless interface is already connected to some other AP, first disconnect it using

   ```
    nmcli con down <AP name>
   ```

   **Example**: Supposing interface is already connected to '*PreviousAP*', then  disconnect it using

   ```
    nmcli con down PreviousAP
   ```
2. Now for Connecting to new AP

   Considering you know the AP name and password.

   ```
    nmcli device wifi connect <AP name> password <password>
   ```

   **Example**: AP name: *Connect-to-this*. WPA/WPA2 PSK: iampassword123

   ```
    nmcli device wifi connect Connect-to-this password iampassword123
   ```

   If you don't want to have the wireless password stored in your history in recent versions you can add `--ask` to have `nmcli` prompt you for missing information it needs (default behavior if password is not provided).

This will automatically create a file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` with the `AP name`, which will contain the configuration.

```
ls /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Connect-to-this
```

Tested in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how to connect to a new wifi network

Comment: This still works in ubuntu 18.04 even during the live installer! Thanks! `ifup` did not work for me, so I used `sudo ip link set wlan0 up`

Comment: does that also create new AP names for you whenever you run this command on ubuntu 18.04?

Answer (score 15):

**To turn on WiFi**

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
nmcli networking on
```

**To list WiFi Networks**

```
nmcli connection show
```

Output should be something like this

```
NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Rishbh-Q1000              cd79a7a1-1cf4-49c3-ad58-21ab17d1ba05   802-11-wireless   Thursday 18 September 2014 05:32:34 PM IST
```

`ncmli` allows you to connect via The **UUID** or **ID (NAME, [SSID](https://askubuntu.com/a/1004949/349837))**

**Usage :**

```
 nmcli connection { COMMAND | help }
   COMMAND := { show | status | up | down | delete }

   show [id <id> | uuid <id>]
   status [id <id> | uuid <id> | path <path>]
   up id <id> | uuid <id> [iface <iface>] [ap <BSSID>] [--nowait] [--timeout <timeout>]
   down id <id> | uuid <id>
   delete id <id> | uuid <id>
```

**Example Usage in this case**

- ***Connect :***

  ```
    nmcli c up uuid cd79a7a1-1cf4-49c3-ad58-21ab17d1ba05
  ```

  or

  ```
    nmcli c up id Rishbh-Q1000
  ```
- ***Connect on specific wlan interface :***

  ```
    nmcli c up id Rishbh-Q1000 iface wlan1
  ```

  or

  ```
    nmcli c up uuid cd79a7a1-1cf4-49c3-ad58-21ab17d1ba05 iface wlan1
  ```
- ***Disconnect :***

  ```
    nmcli c down id Rishbh-Q1000
  ```

  or

  ```
    nmcli c down uuid cd79a7a1-1cf4-49c3-ad58-21ab17d1ba05
  ```

Comment: Error: 'list' is not valid 'connection' command. (nmcli tool, version 1.2.6)

Comment: 'list' has been replaced with 'show' in newer version of nmcli

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore. For `nmcli c up uuid cd79a7a1-1cf4-49c3-ad58-21ab17d1ba05 iface wlan1` I  get "Error: invalid extra argument 'iface'."

Comment: From `nmcli c --help`: the correct usage is `nmcli c up uuid cd79a7a1-1cf4-49c3-ad58-21ab17d1ba05 ifname wlan1`. So **ifname** instead of **iface**!