# Difference between essid, bssid and ssid in commands?

Tags: networking, wireless

If I am correct, ESS is the union of a set of BSS's. ESSID and BSSID are just their IDs respectively.

How can I tell if a wireless network has essid, bssid or ssid? 
What differences are between usages of essid, bssid and ssid? When to use which?

Which one should apply to the wireless network created by my router in my apartment: ESSID, BSSID, or SSID?

Some examples of commands that use ESSID, BSSID or SSID as their arguments. But I am not sure why they use one not the others.

1. The manpage of `iwconfig` says

   ```
   NAME
          iwconfig - configure a wireless network interface

   SYNOPSIS
          iwconfig [interface]
          iwconfig interface [essid X] [nwid N] [mode M] [freq F]
                             [channel C][sens S ][ap A ][nick NN ]
                             [rate R] [rts RT] [frag FT] [txpower T]
                             [enc E] [key K] [power P] [retry R]
                             [modu M] [commit]
          iwconfig --help
          iwconfig --version
   ```

   Why does it have an argument `essid` rather than `bssid`? Does a
   wireless network interface always work with a ESS not a BSS?
2. `wpa_cli` has a command

   ```
      bssid <network id> <BSSID>
             set preferred BSSID for an SSID
   ```

   Why does it use BSSID instead of ESSID as `iwconfig` does?
3. `wpa_passphrase` uses an argument for a SSID, does it mean the
   argument can be either BSSID or ESSID?

   ```
   SYNOPSIS
          wpa_passphrase [ ssid ] [ passphrase ]
   ```
4. `wicd-wired-settings.conf` has the following settings:

   ```
      bssid = <BSSID_of_network>
             This value can be found using iwconfig(8).

      essid = <ESSID_of_network>
             This value can be found using iwconfig(8).
   ```

   Can `iwconfig` tell if a network is ESS or BSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My understanding is that ESSID is the name of the access point, which can be changed. On the other hand, BSSID is a numeric ID of the access point (something like the MAC address of the router). For instance, on my college campus we have many different access points with the same name, but BSSIDs are different for each router.

You can list networks with their respective ESSID and BSSID with

```
nmcli dev wifi
```

Or for cleaner output you can do `nmcli -f SSID,BSSID dev wifi`.

Also with `iwlist`, for example:

```
sudo iwlist wlp2s0 scan
```

Answer (score 5):

Types of **S**ervice **S**ets:

- **BSS** (**B**asic **S**ervice **S**et)
- **ESS** (**E**xtended **S**ervice **S**et). **ESS**s consist of one or more infrastructure-BBSs (the usual mode). They are associated with multiple access points. All the APs' beacons will broadcast the same SSID but different BSSIDs. It involves roaming. The user gets connected to the AP that has maximum strength. Usually, nearby BSSs broadcast on different channels/frequencies.

[image: diagram]

**ID**entification:

- **SSID**: Network name (friendly, text, even with non-ISO basic Latin characters, up to 64 characters). Could be hidden (no broadcast). Sometimes "wrongly" called ESSID since it might group a set of APs under one name, but [there is formally no such thing as an ESSID in the 802.11 standards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_set_(802.11_network)#Extended_service_set).
- **BSSID**: MAC address of the access point, it uniquely identifies each one.

You can use these commands to get a lot of information of nearby networks:

```sh
nmcli -f NAME,SSID,SSID-HEX,BSSID,MODE,CHAN,FREQ,RATE,SIGNAL,BARS,SECURITY,WPA-FLAGS,RSN-FLAGS,DEVICE,ACTIVE,IN-USE,DBUS-PATH device wifi
# Or just nmcli device wifi
```

or `iwlist wlp2s0 scanning`, but since commands from [`net-tools`](https://web.archive.org/web/20210225113110/https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/net-tools) and `wireless-tools` packages [seem to be deprecated in Linux](https://dougvitale.wordpress.com/2011/12/21/deprecated-linux-networking-commands-and-their-replacements/#iwconfig) you could try to get familiar with the modern [`iw` from `iproute2` package](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2):

```
iw dev wlp2s0 scan dump
```

### Reference

- [Understanding the Network Terms SSID, BSSID, and ESSID](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos-space-apps/network-director2.0/topics/concept/wireless-ssid-bssid-essid.html)
- [What's the difference between a BSSID and an ESSID? - Quora](https://www.quora.com/Whats-the-difference-between-a-BSSID-and-an-ESSID)

### See also

- [Fast BSS Transition](https://blogs.cisco.com/networking/what-is-802-11r-why-is-this-important) (AKA 802.11r, AKA Fast Roaming)